# Android http connection exception

Tags: android

I have some problems with my Android 3.1 emulator. I can't get my XML file.

```
protected InputStream getInputStream() {
    try {

        return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Here's the error trace:

```
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1038)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:523)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at maps.test.BaseFeedParser.getInputStream(BaseFeedParser.java:30)
08-07 22:34:26.657: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(563):     at maps.test.DomFeedParser.parse(DomFeedParser.java:23)
```

I think I can't connect to Internet , even with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`. But in the same time, the Google API is working very well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

In Honeycomb they've gone and put in a trap to catch people trying to do potentially time-consuming network operations on the main thread.

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html).
>
> Also see [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html).

(Please note that you could have instantly found this yourself by doing a web search on the exception at the top of the error messages you posted.)

Because things like looking up a host name can take a long and somewhat indeterminate amount of time, they should not be called from the event functions on the main thread which are required to return quickly (as in within a few milliseconds).  If one of these functions takes too long to return, Android loses the ability to send messages to the program, and may pop up the dreaded Application Not Responding dialog.

You should move your networking operations (at least any that require waiting for a result or for a blockage to clear so you can send more) to a thread.  If the network operations are coming from an piece of API code, you probably shouldn't be calling that on the main thread.

Comment: i am recieving the same error but i have my http work in a seperate thread i.e. async task. what could have gone wrong? could you please guide me on this?

Comment: You have probably not used async task correctly, and either not put all the network operations in the background method, or else called the background method from the ui thread rather than starting the async task.  When you examine your stack trace you will find out which.

Comment: i checked thoroughly, the http call is called in the doInBackground() method which is called from the .execute() command, still the stream returns: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.FixedLengthInputStream@405259f0

Answer (score 15):

Use Async Task  or

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) 
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Comment: This is such a great hint for all kinds of quick evaluation. You don't have to lose time with thread/async details. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Do you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your Android Manifest?  It should be above your `application` tag

Comment: I allready add it, Dont forget that i said google API work very well.

Comment: but you think that Google API can work without get connected?
beceause MyLocationOverlay dont work! but I can acces to the map and add static Overlay


    </application>
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>

Comment: Try moving the uses-permission tag above the application tag, so it's <mainfest ... > <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <application ... >

Comment: same as the other answer, Chris Stratton got it right, its just because of network NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 3):

This exception is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher.
you may be targeting your sdk equal to or higher than api level 11. Just change it to api level 8 or other api level below 11. your problem may be solved

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722987/error-while-publishing-photo-on-facebook-wall-using-android-facebook-sdk/8724799#8724799) is the same problem, it had solved by change api level.

I hope it helps you.!!

Comment: Actually the way I understood it, this exception is thrown on purpose to prevent time-consuming network operations on the main thread. So the problem is not the API he's targeting but the way he handles network operations ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  android:targetSdkVersion"version_number" from your AndroidManifest.xml

I removed it and my problem solved