# Flex mobile Android 4 network access

Tags: android, apache-flex, networking, mobile

I have a mobile Android application written in Flex 4 connected to the facebook. It's worked perfect, but know I have problems for Android 4 . 
The problems is that my application can't access the internet. 
Do you know if there are some restriction in Android 4 or something different which can 
cause this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stuart's answer pinpoints the most likely reason. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976317/android-http-conncetion-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to update to AIR 3.2 . And also the problem is not fixed fot the Android emulator. So after update to AIR 3.2 its work on the device , but not on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 4, you're not allowed to do network communication in the main thread anymore. Could this be the problem?