# Unfortunately, myapp has stopped when login

Tags: php, android

I am new to Android, and I am trying make a simple app like Sales App. When I run the app in the emulator, it gives the message:

> Unfortunately, Sales has Stopped.

This is my login

```
package com.stmik.slidingmenu.utama;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.stmik.slidingmenu.R;
import com.stmik.slidingmenu.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.stmik.slidingmenu.library.UserFunctions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;         

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

     Button btnLogin;
     Button btnLinkToRegister;
     EditText inputEmail;
     EditText inputPassword;
     TextView loginErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
        private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
        private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
        private static String KEY_UID = "kode";
        private static String KEY_NAME = "nama";
        private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
        private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "dibuat_tgl";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);

            // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
            btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
            loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

            // Login button Click Event
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                    JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                    // check for login response
                    try {
                        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                            if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                                // user successfully logged in
                                // Store user details in SQLite Database
                                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                                JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                                // Clear all previous data in database
                                userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                                db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                                // Launch Dashboard Screen
                                Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                                // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                                dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(dashboard);

                                // Close Login Screen
                                finish();
                            }else{
                                // Error in login
                                loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });    

            // Link to Register Screen
            btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

this is my userfunction

```
package com.stmik.slidingmenu.library;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;

public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    // Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp 
    // use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
    private static String loginURL = "http://192.168.0.100/sales_app/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://192.168.0.100/sales_app/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String nama, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama", nama));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }


}
```

this is my json

```
package com.stmik.slidingmenu.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

and here is the logcat

```
05-25 07:40:47.450: D/dalvikvm(837): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 51K, 7% free 2570K/2744K, paused 47ms, total 50ms
05-25 07:40:47.460: I/dalvikvm-heap(837): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.232MB for 635812-byte allocation
05-25 07:40:47.520: D/dalvikvm(837): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 6% free 3186K/3368K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
05-25 07:40:47.600: D/dalvikvm(837): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3203K/3368K, paused 39ms+4ms, total 81ms
05-25 07:40:55.924: I/Choreographer(837): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-25 07:40:56.094: D/gralloc_goldfish(837): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-25 07:40:56.424: I/Choreographer(837): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-25 07:40:58.764: D/AndroidRuntime(837): Shutting down VM
05-25 07:40:58.794: W/dalvikvm(837): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.stmik.slidingmenu.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:42)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.stmik.slidingmenu.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:40)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.stmik.slidingmenu.utama.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:55)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-25 07:40:58.844: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 07:45:59.016: I/Process(837): Sending signal. PID: 837 SIG: 9
```

and php code

```
class DB_Functions {

private $db;

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($nama_sales, $email_sales, $password_sales, $alamat_sales, $hp_sales, $telp_sales) {
    $uuid_sales = uniqid('', true);
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO m_sales(unique_id_sales, nama_sales, email_sales, password_sales, alamat_sales, hp_sales, telp_sales, dibuat_tgl) VALUES('$uuid_sales', '$nama_sales', '$email_sales', '$password_sales','$alamat_sales', '$hp_sales', '$telp_sales', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid_sales = mysql_insert_id(); //last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM m_sales WHERE uid_sales = $uid_sales");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get user by email_sales and password_sales
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email_sales, $password_sales) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM m_sales WHERE email_sales = '$email_sales'") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);           
        $password_sales = $result['password_sales'];                        
    } else {
        // user not found
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email_sales) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email_sales from m_sales WHERE email_sales = '$email_sales'");
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        return false;
    }
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6986726/1836697

The important part from your logcat is

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

You are not allowed to run network threads on the main thread. Use a separate thread to do network tasks and you should be allright.

Comment: I'm sorry but where is the notwork tasks? is it to get data from database? if so, I already made a different class to get the data from database, which one should i wrapped with asynctask? the login activity or the getdatabase activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can not perform a network operation on the main thread. Try wrapping your network code in a new Thread or use an AsyncTask.

Comment: Ups sorry. Meant to say "can not". Corrected the answer.

Comment: thank u for ur answer. Finally I can login without any error, coz I use a thread. thank u.. >.<