# E/JSON Parser(1506): Error parsing data [End of input at character 0 of ]

Tags: java, php, json

my app which is supposed to transfer user input data to my SQL database. I am supposed to fill in all fields, then click save so that data gets updated in my sql databse. After cleaning up a lot of errors, i am finally stuck on 1 error that i cant resolve. any help provided would be extremely appreciated.Please advice what changes i can make to get rid of the error. The error is

```
       08-04 05:47:48.799: E/JSON Parser(1506): Error parsing data [End of input at character 0 of ]
```

My codes below:

```
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputDriver;
    EditText inputLicence;
    EditText inputOfficer;
    EditText inputSpeed;
    EditText FineAppl;
    EditText inputCategory;
    TextView registerFine;

    // url to create new fine
    private static String url_create_fine = "http://192.168.1.1/android_api/create.php";

    // JSON Node names/
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        speed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);    
        Fine = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText4);  
        btnSelectDate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectDate);
        btnSelectTime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectTime);
        inputDriver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        inputLicence = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        inputOfficer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        inputSpeed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        FineAppl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        inputCategory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        registerFine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fineregistered);


        // Create button
       Button btnRegisterfine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savefine);





                        // button click event
                        btnRegisterfine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // creating new product in background thread
                                new CreateNewFine().execute();
                            }


                      });
        }
                        /**
                         * Background Async Task to Create new product
                         * */
                        class CreateNewFine extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


                            @Override
                            protected void onPreExecute() {
                                super.onPreExecute();
                                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FineCalc.this);
                                pDialog.setMessage("Registering Fine..");
                                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                                pDialog.show();
                            }


                            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                                String driver = inputDriver.getText().toString();
                                String licencenum = inputLicence.getText().toString();
                                String officer = inputOfficer.getText().toString();
                                String speed = inputSpeed.getText().toString();
                                String fine= FineAppl.getText().toString();
                                String category = inputCategory.getText().toString();


                                // Building Parameters
                                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver", driver));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("licencenum", licencenum));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("officer", officer));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("speed", speed));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fine", fine));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", category));

                                // getting JSON Object
                                // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_fine, "POST", params);


                                // check log cat from response
                                //Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                                // check for success tag
                                try {
                                       //if (json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS) != null) {
                                    if(json != null && !(json).isNull(TAG_SUCCESS)){
                                    registerFine.setText("");
                                    String success = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
                                   // int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                                   // if (success == 1) {
                                    if(Integer.parseInt(success) == 1){
                                        // successfully created product
                                       //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserLogin.class);
                                        //startActivity(i);
                                        registerFine.setText("Successful");

                                        // closing this screen
                                        finish();
                                    } else {
                                    }   // failed to create product
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                return null;
                            }
```

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
               // is, HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
       // Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data [" + e.getMessage()+"] "+json);
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}


}



                            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                                // dismiss the dialog once done
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                            }

                        }
```

And My php

```
      <?php


// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['driver'], $_POST['licencenum'], $_POST['officer'], $_POST['speed'] , $_POST['fine'],$_POST['category'])){

$driver = $_POST['driver'];
$licencenum = $_POST['licencenum'];
$officer = $_POST['officer'];
$speed = $_POST['speed'];
$fine = $_POST['fine'];
$category = $_POST['category'];


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fineregister(driver,licencenum,officer,speed,fine,category) VALUES                ('$driver','$licencenum','$officer','$speed','$fine',      '$category')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Speed Ticket Successfully Registered.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't post the whole code because its hard to debug. So post relevant code.

Comment: And *please* format your code before posting. It's *horribly* hard to read at the moment, with indentation all over the place and huge spans of whitespace.

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't included the full exception stack trace, either :( Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Note that you now have six questions, two of which have downvotes and none of which have upvotes. If you continue to ask bad questions, you will be automatically banned from asking any more - so please put some effort into making your questions better.

Comment: yet another json error. Rule number 1: Always make sure the files that you are reading from a json object corresponds to what you want, e.g. if you want int, make sure it is an int not a string.

Comment: ohhh god, my apologies. beginner here so still learning :(

Comment: ok so iam totally missing where the int and string error is. a bit of guidance please. still in learning stages

Comment: looks like your PHP file returning invalid response ,debug your php side whether the  return json value  is well formed structure

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

pass the string into json array and get the response value

            JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
            JSONObject js = jsArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String returnvalmsg = js.getString("message");
            String returnvalsucc = js.getString("success");
```

Hint: pass success as "0" not 0

Comment: I am sorry for asking this but i am an utter newbie at this. Where and how would i add this code.

Comment: in json parser.java. if(method=="post") change the last two lines i.e get  is as string instead of input stream

Comment: so iam trying this but i get a client cannot be resolved over here
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

Comment: sorted the above out but now i get this weird error
08-05 09:15:18.787: E/Buffer Error(2342): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
08-05 09:15:18.787: E/JSON Parser(2342): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: Debug the php side check whether its returning null or value.