# XML Parser - try-catch not working

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a class with:

```
public String chceXML() {
    try {
        Document doc = loadTestDocument("http://meteo.pl/xml_um_date.php");
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("data");        

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

             return eElement
                        .getElementsByTagName("act_model_date")
                        .item(0)
                        .getTextContent()
                        .replace(" ","")
                    .toString();
           }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "wrong";
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I show it by:

```
XMLParser dM = new XMLParser();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "XML: "+dM.chceXML(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And unfortunately it is "wrong".

By the way, it working in NETBeans! But not working in Android Studio.

Please help me!

Comment: *And I show it: (in other activity of corse :))

Comment: Provide the stack trace you get while this exception occures

Comment: I/Error: Some exception occurred
                                                                android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1315)

Comment: in your manifest, did you put the networking persmission ?

Comment: yes, i have:    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: use this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093546/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-at-android-os-strictmodeandroidblockgua "this might help you out")!